# Is there a restriction on the no. of HERE API Calls I can make in a loop (using R)

Tags: r, here-api, rjsonio

I am trying to loop through a list of origin destination lat long locations to get the transit time. I am getting the following error when I loop. However when I do a single call (without looping), I get an output without error. I use the freemium HERE-API and I am allowed 250k transactions a month.

```
 `for (i in 1:nrow(test))        
   { 
            call <- paste0("https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json",
                           "?app_id=","appid",
                           "&app_code=","appcode",
                           "&waypoint0=geo!",y$dc_lat[i],",",y$dc_long[i],
                           "&waypoint1=geo!",y$store_lat[i],",",y$store_long[i],
                           "&mode=","fastest;truck;traffic:enabled",
                           "&trailerscount=","1",
                           "&routeattributes=","sh",
                           "&maneuverattributes=","di,sh",
                           "&limitedweight=","20")

                  response <-fromJSON(call, simplify = TRUE)
            Traffic_time = (response[["response"]][["route"]][[1]][["summary"]][["trafficTime"]]) / 60
            Base_time = (response[["response"]][["route"]][[1]][["summary"]][["baseTime"]]) / 60
            print(Traffic_time)
}`
```

> `Error in file(con, "r"): cannot open the connection to 'https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=appid&app_code=appcode&waypoint0=geo!45.1005200,-93.2452000&waypoint1=geo!45.0978500,-95.0413620&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&trailerscount=1&routeattributes=sh&maneuverattributes=di,sh&limitedweight=20'
>   Traceback:`

Comment: You loop `i in 1:nrow(test)` but access `y$dc_lat[i]` and `y$store_lat[i]`. Are you sure these rows exist in `y`?

Comment: Great call out Rui, yes the same rows exist in y. Eitherways, I did modify 'y' to 'test' and the loop errors out on the 11th row.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, this suggests that there is problem with the file at your end.  it could be corrupt, good to try with changing the extension of the file. Can also try to restart your IDE. The number of API calls depend on the plans that you have opted for freemium or pro plans. You can have more details : https://developer.here.com/faqs